# How to reduce download for HTML5 game on mobiles devices (iOS etc)?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML5 game I have been working on that is using a couple of JavaScript libraries that are approx 1.5mb combined (minified) and have approx 1.5mb of assets (3D models and PNG textures).
My actual game code adds a measly 50kb on top.
All in all it's a little over 3mb.

I have 2 questions:

1. While I am developing and testing the main 3rd party libraries and the game assets are not changing. Only the 50kb or so game logic is changing.
   Can I test on a mobile device (in my case Safari in iPhone) and have all those libraries and assets loaded the once, and only download the revised game logic files?
2. If I share the URL with friends, are they going to be forced to download the whole lot every time they reload the page?

I guess bottom line is what, if any, caching options are there to avoid constant reload of static (unchanging) libraries/assets?

Any help / advice appreciated.

Thanks

Martin

Answer (score 0):

- JavaScript libraries - if it is a popular library, it will be more efficient to load them from CDN since it is more likely that the browser cached it from other site.
- You can split the code to two minify/uglify files and for the file that is not likely to be changed add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header in server:  https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html?guccounter=1#expires
- Use Gzip (you can also find it in the above link) which will reduce the size of the response files.
- You can add a service worker combined with Cache interface (service worker not supported on all browsers) to cache JS files including assets (e.g. images):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response. I also came across Application Cache / Manifest files after I made that post. Is that anything of use, or not recommended?

Comment: Applications Cache is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache .
I don't think that Manifest file alone will help you with cache issues, but it is a good idea to add it for the user to have the app on home screen and without mobile status header.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice. Good food for thought. Thank you.